# Button event to animation

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MovingCircleGUI
{
    JFrame frame;

    public int x,y;
    public int vx = 30,vy=20;
    public int width = 500,height = 500;
    public int diameter=100;

    CircleDrawPanel drawPanel;
    Color color = Color.magenta.darker();
    JButton button;
    Timer timer2 = new Timer(10, new AnimateCircleListener());

    boolean isRunning = false;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        MovingCircleGUI gui = new MovingCircleGUI();
        gui.go();
    }

    //this method sets up the JFrame and adds the draw panel to the frame
    public void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("MovingCircleGUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        drawPanel = new CircleDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

        button = new JButton("Click me to start the animation");
        drawPanel.add(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH , button);
        button.addActionListener(new  AnimateCircleListener());

        frame.setSize(width,height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CircleDrawPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.fillOval(x,y,diameter,diameter);
        }
    }

    public void MovingBall()
    {

        x = x + vx;
        y = y + vy;

            if( y >= height)
            {
                y=0;
                boolean xIsSame = true;
                int randomX = 0;
                do
                {
                    randomX = Math.round((float)Math.random()*width);

                    if (randomX != x)
                    {
                        x = randomX;
                    }

                }
                while(!xIsSame);
            }

            if(x <= 0)
            {
                x = width+x;
            }

            if (x >= width)
            {
                x = x-width;
            }

            timer2.start();
            frame.repaint();

    }

    class AnimateCircleListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getSource()== button)
            {
                if(isRunning)
                {
                    isRunning = false;
                    button.setText("Click me to start the animation");
                    button.revalidate();
                }
                 else
                {
                    isRunning = true;
                    MovingBall();
                    button.setText("Click me to stop the animation");
                    button.revalidate();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public int getX() 
    {
            return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) 
    {
            this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() 
    {
            return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) 
    {
            this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I am trying to construct a one button which handles two events mainly to start and stop the animation. What I am trying to do is when the user clicks the button the animation of the bouncing ball will start, and the text of the button will change to "Click me to stop", and when the user clicks the button again the animation will stop. I am using the timer.

The animation is okay, I worked that out, and that when the user clicks the button, the animation start that's okay too. The only problem I've got is how am I going to handle another event to the same button?

Comment: Can you show the code? Then more relevant answers can be provided.

Comment: yes sorry i inputted my animation method.

Comment: `if (timer2.isRunning()) ...`?

Comment: Can I ask why my answer was unaccepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something similar to this. This way you only need one `Action Listener` and a `boolean` to tell it which action to do.

```
boolean isRunning = false

button.addActionListener(new YourActionListener());

public class YourActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==button)
        {
            if(isRunning)
            {
                isRunning = false;
                button.setText("Click me to start");
                button.revalidate();
            }
            else
            {
                isRunning = true;
                button.setText("Click me to stop");
                button.revalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Your code now works. What you wanted to do was call the `MoveBall` method when `timer2` fired the `Action Listener`.

This can be done by

```
if(e.getSource()==timer2)
{
    MovingBall();
}
```

so in your code it would look like.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MovingCircleGUI
{
    JFrame frame;

    public int x,y;
    public int vx = 10,vy=5;
    public int width = 500,height = 500;
    public int diameter=50;

    CircleDrawPanel drawPanel;
    Color color = Color.magenta.darker();
    JButton button;
    Timer timer2 = new Timer(25, new AnimateCircleListener());

    boolean isRunning = false;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        MovingCircleGUI gui = new MovingCircleGUI();
        gui.go();
    }

    //this method sets up the JFrame and adds the draw panel to the frame
    public void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("MovingCircleGUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        drawPanel = new CircleDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

        button = new JButton("Click me to start the animation");
        drawPanel.add(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH , button);
        button.addActionListener(new  AnimateCircleListener());

        frame.setSize(width,height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CircleDrawPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.fillOval(x,y,diameter,diameter);
        }
    }

    public void MovingBall()
    {
        x = x + vx;
        y = y + vy;

        if( y >= height)
        {
            y=0;
            boolean xIsSame = true;
            int randomX = 0;
            do
            {
                randomX = Math.round((float)Math.random()*width);

                if (randomX != x)
                {
                    x = randomX;
                }

            }
            while(!xIsSame);
        }

        if(x <= 0)
        {
            x = width+x;
        }

        if (x >= width)
        {
            x = x-width;
        }

        frame.repaint();
    }

    class AnimateCircleListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getSource()== button)
            {
                if(timer2.isRunning())
                {
                    button.setText("Click me to start the animation");
                    button.revalidate();
                    timer2.stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    button.setText("Click me to stop the animation");
                    button.revalidate();
                    timer2.start();
                }
            }

            if(e.getSource()==timer2)
            {
                MovingBall();
            }
        }
    }

    public int getX() 
    {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) 
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() 
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) 
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried working out with a similiar code already but the animation the bouncing ball starts and stop immediately.

Comment: @Zajra11 The problem with my original code was it was saying `if(boolean true)` set it to false and then it was saying `if(boolean false)` set it to true so it did both actions. It will not do that anymore

Comment: @Zajra11 If that works for you could you accept the answer using the tick next to the answer. I would be grateful

Comment: Thanks alot for your help..the button texts changing works fine now.. i am trying to work out on the start animation method.. since it is only moving once when the button is clicked .

Comment: @Zajra11 Can you edit your question and show us some code and I should be able to tailor my answer a little bit more specifically

Comment: @Zajra11 My edit on my answer should be a bit more helpful

Comment: @Zajra11 See [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/21-java-awt/2271-how-to-create-a-bouncing-ball-animation.html) or [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html) for a little more information on bouncing balls in java

Comment: i'm still trying.. the buttons are working fine tough, the text is changing the only problem i have is the animation.. i am make some research aswell..

Comment: no it does not work, the ball does not even move now :/

Comment: @Zajra11 Edited a copy to have something which you wanted. Take a look at new edit

Comment: @Zajra11 Changed edit one from `while` to `if` which should fix. If not take a look a edit 2

Comment: still no :/ i re-started my code, because i am using the timer not the thread.. but still facing the same problem.. the button texts are changing but the ball is moving once and stops.

Comment: @Zajra11 Could you post the whole of your code in your question?

Comment: @Zajra11 Edited answer to include fix

Comment: @Zajra11 Wonderful. If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer I would be grateful

Comment: hi sorry to post again.. i am trying to answer a question but i am not sure what method should i use to sort 3 different classes? .. i have a class called sorting.. which sorts one class only at the moment.. i would like to amend this class to sort another 2 classes.. therefore a total of 3 classes.

Comment: @Zajra11 Send me a link to the question so I can get a better idea of what you are saying but can you not just call your sort class again?

Comment: import java.util.Comparator;

public class Sorting implements Comparator<Student>
{
 @Override
 public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) 
 {
  String n1 = s1.getAuthor();
  String n2 = s2.getAuthor();

  return n1.compareTo(n2);
 }
 
}

this is my class at the moment which is comparing and sorting only the student class.. in my question i have that i need to amend this class so that it can be used to sort not just objects of the student class but also another 2 classes objects.

Thanks alot for your help !

Comment: @Zajra11 Hang on taking a little longer to write than I thought

Comment: @Zajra11 Updated. Any luck?

Comment: i think i shall use the return after the if else statements right?

Comment: @Zajra11 Switched to your other question

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the previous `ActionListener` on the `JButton` using `button.removeActionListener(<your first action listener>)` and then add the second action listener using `button.addActionListener(<your second action listener>)`. Then, to change the text on the button, just use `button.setText("Your Text Here")`.